# Is it possible to order airag at bars in Mongolia?

Tags: food-and-drink, mongolia, local-cuisine

I've been to a couple of bars, mainly up-market, in Mongolia, and none of them seemed to have [airag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airag) (fermented horse milk) in the drinks list. I was able to drink some airag at a ger next to a highway which was advertised by a sign hand-written in Mongolian, however.

Is it possible to order airag in bars?

Comment: @pnuts I visited late August early September.

Comment: The only time I had it was at a private home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, **no**.  Airag is a seasonal, niche, perishable product, that as far as I can tell is not commercially produced and is hence not regularly available at supermarkets, liquor stores or bars.

Visiting Ulaanbaatar just before the Naadam festival a few years ago, I did see a few pop-up stalls selling the stuff, but generally it's made at home and only sold where produced.

[image]

In the picture above, the airag was produced in the *ger* (yurt) it was sold in, more specifically in the blue plastic barrel in the background.  Эрүүл мэндийн төлөө!

Answer (score 5):

I had airag from a roadside ger (that was obviously tourist-friendly) in Ulan Bataar years ago, in late July or early August.